# NextJS 13 - Data is not being refetched on router push

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a delete user button on my user page (route: /users/[username]) who call the delete user api's route.
Then after this call, i execute a `router.psuh('/users')` to go back to my users list
But my `/users` page is like cached and the data is not re fetched.

This is my delete user button :

```js
"use client"

import deleteUser from "@/lib/users/deleteUser"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache"
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

type Props = {
  user: User
}

export default function DeleteUserButton({ user }: Props) {
  const router = useRouter()

  const deleteUserCallback = async (id: string) => {
    deleteUser(id)
    .then(() => {
      router.push("/users")
    })
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteUserCallback(user.id)}>
      Delete
    </button>
  )
}
```

My user page :

```js
import getUserByUsername from "@/lib/users/getUserByUsername"
import DeleteUserButton from "./components/DeleteUserButton"

type Props = {
  params: {
    username: string
  }
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params: { username } }: Props) {
  const user = await getUserByUsername(username)

  if (user === null) {
    return {
      title: "User not found",
    }
  }

  return {
    title: `${user.lastName} ${user.firstName}`,
  }
}

export default async function UserPage({ params: { username } }: Props) {
  const user = await getUserByUsername(username)

  if (user === null) {
    return <div>User not found</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>User: {user.email}</p>
      <DeleteUserButton user={user} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And then my users page :

```
import getUsers from "@/lib/users/getUsers"
import Link from "next/link"

export default async function UsersPage() {
  const usersReq = await getUsers()
  const users = usersReq.users

  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <p key={user.id}>
            <Link href={`/users/${user.username}`}>
              {user.username}
            </Link>
            {user.firstName}
          </p>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Idk if i have to change my fetch users list method ?

---

UPDATE

My getUsers function (i'm using an external API):

```js
export default async function getUsers():
  Promise<{
    users: User[],
    pagination: Pagination
  }>
{
  const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + '/users?pageSize=20', {
    cache: 'no-cache',
  });

  if (!res.ok)
    throw new Error('Error fetching');

  return res.json();
}
```

If i add a tag with a revalidateTag it looks like this :

(getUsers)

```js
export default async function getUsers():
  Promise<{
    users: User[],
    pagination: Pagination
  }>
{
  const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + '/users?pageSize=20', {
    cache: 'no-cache',
    next: {
      tags: ['users']
    }
  });

  if (!res.ok)
    throw new Error('Error fetching');

  return res.json();
}
```

And now my DeleteUserButton component :

```js
"use client"

import deleteUser from "@/lib/users/deleteUser"
import { revalidateTag } from "next/cache"
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

type Props = {
  user: User
}

export default function DeleteUserButton({ user }: Props) {
  const router = useRouter()

  const deleteUserCallback = async (id: string) => {
    deleteUser(id)
    .then(() => {
      revalidateTag("users")
      router.push("/users")
    })
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteUserCallback(user.id)}>
      Delete
    </button>
  )
}
```

But now i get this error when i click on the delete button :
[image: error]

Comment: Have you read [the documentation around fetch caching behavior](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching)?

Comment: @argbo Yes but i think im missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to execute the `revalidate` directly from a `Client Component` that is seems to be not possible.

To execute a `revalidatePath` / `revalidateTag` from a `Client Component` :

- Request a route handler: [Route handler documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) - [revalidatePath example in route handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath)
- [Use server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions) to execute a function on the server from a client

And now it works ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to invalidate the cache when a user is created / updated / deleted, or disable it for `getUsers` altogether:

- Invalidate the cache on demand for a path using [`revalidatePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) or for a tag using [`revalidateTag`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidateTag).
- [Disable the cache altogether](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching) for that individual `fetch` request with `fetch('https://...', { cache: 'no-store' })`.

You can read more about this in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating).

**Edit:**

About the error you are getting:

```
Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag users
```

This might be a bug on Vercel's side, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50714).

Comment: I forgot to include the getUsers code:

`
export default async function getUsers():
  Promise<{
    users: User[],
    pagination: Pagination
  }>
{
  const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + '/users?pageSize=20', {
    cache: 'no-cache',
  });

  if (!res.ok)
    throw new Error('Error fetching');

  return res.json();
}`

I already had no-cache

If i add a tag to the request and i execute revalidate in my DeleteUserButton component i have an error : Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag users

Comment: @LoisDuplain I think it's better if you update the question with all relevant code / comments. I'll take a look later if no one answers it before.

Comment: @Danwiger Sorry i updated it correctly

Comment: This answer is correct. Your sample code uses `no-cache`, whereas the correct value is `no-store`. With that option set correctly you should not need the erroring revalidateTag call.

Comment: @argbo It doesn't work any better

Comment: @LoisDuplain This might be a bug on Vercel's side, see [this bug report](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50714).

Comment: @Danziger My app is not published on Vercel
The bug happens locally

Comment: Are you still getting an error, or does it just appear that nothing is happening? To troubleshoot next, I would check if `getUsers` is running when you navigate back to `/users`. It still should run. If it's running, I would check if it's firing a network request from within `getUsers`.

Comment: @argbo It was because i tried to execute a revalidate in my client component...
So i activated the server actions feature and converted my deleteUser function to a server action but idk if its a good practice and if there is a better way to do that ?